# How to include shortcodes and pdfs in WordPress search without plugin?

Tags: shortcode, search, pdf

I have a WordPress website using Avada theme. The website uses an inbuilt WordPress search tool which searches only posts. The website uses shortcode to add toggle/ accordion etc. I want to include search results from accordions/ tabs etc?

I need to include results from toggle/ accordions/ pdfs etc. It is fine if possible to include the page containing toggle?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the content from the accordion coming from? If it was in the post I'd have thought that the search would include it already?

Comment: Hi Rup, The accordion in the website is a shortcode. The shortcode looks like this [fusion_toggle][/fusion_toggle].  I have a PDF added inside this toggle and I want to make this toggle appear in search result. At least want the page containing the toggle. Now the search result goes to 'Not Found' page if search any text in title or content of the toggle.